# Typescript: Wait for all promises

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i got a small problem with my promises.

This is my function:

```
public generateMealPlanForAWeek(myMealProfile: any, totalCalories:number):Promise<any> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            let mealplan:Array<any> = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
                this.generateMealPlanForOneDay(myMealProfile, totalCalories).then(data => {
                    mealplan.push(data); // resolves much later
                });
            }
            resolve(mealplan); // is resolved instant
        })
    }
```

My problem is, that "generateMealPlanForOneDay" is resolved later then the mealplan itself.

Mealplan is an array of objects (meals in this case).

When i want to save my mealplan, the mealplan is empty:

```
this.storage.set('Mealplan', JSON.stringify(mealplan)).then(....) // meal plan is Array[0]
```

Whats the best way to resolve all meals of my meal plan and then save it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in this case.

```
public generateMealPlanForAWeek(myMealProfile: any, totalCalories:number):Promise<any> {
    var mealPlans = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
       mealPlans.push(this.generateMealPlanForOneDay(myMealProfile, totalCalories));
    }
    return Promise.all(mealPlans);
}

// later
generateMealPlanForAWeek(...).then(mealPlans => ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of working with promises, you can also work with event streams.

The Reactive Extensions for JavaScript (RxJS, see https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS) makes it easy to react to event streams (`Observable`s and their `OnNext`events), or for instance to the end of an event stream (the `OnCompleted`event), to collect the events and save their data.

Here's an interesting example: https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/creating_and_subscribing_to_simple_observable_sequences.html

Comment: Sounds also great! I need to try that! Thanks!