# Waiting for post requests to finish

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a file upload in Angular. To avoid file size restrictions, I implemented an API endpoint that receives chunks of a file. After all chunks are received another endpoint should be called that reassembles the chunks on the server. Therefor I need to know when all post requests are finished. Preferably without using Promises.
The problem is, I'm new to Angular (and even JS) so I'm wondering how this can work.

```js
let i = 0;
for(let offset = 0; offset < file.size; offset += chunkSize) {
  let chunk = file.slice( offset, offset + chunkSize );
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("fileUpload", chunk, file.name + ".part" + i);
  formData.append("identifier", identifier.toString());
  this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "Upload", formData).subscribe();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Wait for all promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122718/typescript-wait-for-all-promises)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put these into an array and utilize `forkJoin` and then subscribe to that.

This will call all the http requests at one time, and the subscribe function will be called once all of them are complete.

```js
let i = 0;
const obsArray = [];
for( let offset = 0; offset < file.size; offset += chunkSize ){
    let chunk = file.slice( offset, offset + chunkSize );

    let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("fileUpload", chunk, file.name + ".part" + i);
      formData.append("identifier", identifier.toString());
    obsArray.push(
      this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "Upload", formData)
    ).
}
forkJoin(obsArray).subscribe();
```

Comment: please mark as tha accepted answer.